# Windows Form - Report viewer 14: pdf size issue

Tags: winforms, pdf, reportviewer

Let me explain my context, we have a windows form application that produce reports with **Report Viewer**. With **visual studio 2017** we had to updgrade to **Report Viewer 2016** but we have seen that the same pdf produced with the previous version (same data I mean) is now double sized, so the rendering and print process is slower.
Anyone had the same problem?
Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we solved the problem.
They were embedded fonts that increased pdf size.
Apparently in the new versions of report viewer this option was not set by default:

```
[bytes] bytes = report.Render("PDF", @"<DeviceInfo><EmbedFonts>None</EmbedFonts></DeviceInfo>", out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);
```